# Python, plot matrix diagonal elements

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I have an 120x70 matrix of which I want to graph diagonal lines.

for ease of typing here, I will explain my problem with a smaller 4x4 matrix.

| index | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 10 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 4 |

I now want to graph for example starting at 2021 index 0
so that I get the following diagonal numbers in a graphs: 2, 8, 10

or if I started at 2020 I would get 1, 5, 5, 4.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple for-loop. e.g.:

```
matrix = np.array((120, 70))
graph_points = []
column_index = 0  # Change this to whatever column you want to start at
for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    graph_points.append(matrix[i, column_index])
    column_index += 1
    if column_index >= matrix.shape[1]:
        break

## Plot graph_points here
```

Comment: Because I had a pandas dataframe I needed to ad .iloc in matrix.iloc[i, column_index]